# Using Jersey with Grizzly

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I want to create a simple REST service, and for that I am using Jersey and Grizzly.

Here is my Service class:

```
@Path("/service")
class TestRESTService {

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    public String test() {
        return "{ \"TestField\" : \"TestValue\" }";
    }

}
```

And from what I understand here is how I supposed to start it:

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.registerClasses(TestRESTService.class);
URI serverUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(19748).build();
HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(serverUri, config);
server.start();
```

But it's not working. :(
I tried to send a request to

```
http://localhost:19748/service/test
```

using Google Chrome's Postman plugin by adding 'Accept' : 'application/json' as a Http Header, but nothing is returned. The 'hourglass' is just spinning around.

Could you please help me?

Comment: That is not valid Java code. *Every* line is missing the closing `;`.

Comment: You are a very good observer, but this doesn't help me! The server starts up. It's logging out INFO: [HttpServer] Started. The reason for this not being a valid Java code is unrelated...

Comment: This code will start up no server. If you need help, please post the real code you are using.

Comment: your code works for me (when I translate it to Java). Can you make a "Preview" in postman and share the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
private static String API_PACKAGE = "package where TestRESTService class";

public static final URI BASE_URI = UriBuilder
        .fromUri("http://localhost/")
        .port(8000)
        .build();

private static HttpServer initServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Starting grizzly... " + BASE_URI);

    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, new HttpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void service(Request rqst, Response rspns) throws Exception {
            rspns.sendError(404);
        }
    });

    // Initialize and register Jersey Servlet
    WebappContext context = new WebappContext("GrizzlyContext", "/");
    ServletRegistration registration = context.addServlet(
            ServletContainer.class.getName(), ServletContainer.class);
    registration.setInitParameter(ServletContainer.RESOURCE_CONFIG_CLASS,
            PackagesResourceConfig.class.getName());
    registration.setInitParameter(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, API_PACKAGE);
    registration.addMapping("/*");
    context.deploy(httpServer);

    return httpServer;
}
```