# Jersey +Grizzly - @ApplicationPath ignored

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I'm running Jersey 2.26-b09 on top of Grizzly, and I'm using the following code to start the Grizzly HTTP server:

```
public void start() {
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("").scheme("http").host("localhost").port(8084).path("/rest").build();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(16);
    String applicationClassName = RestApplication.class.getName();
    String applicationPackageName = RestApplication.class.getPackage().getName();
    String productionPackageName = ProductionService.class.getPackage().getName();
    params.put(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, applicationClassName);
    params.put(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, productionPackageName + "," + applicationPackageName);
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(uri, params);
    server.start();
}
```

The RestApplication class extends Application, and has a @ApplicationPath("/system") annotation.
The ProductionService class is a REST resource with a @Path("/production") annotation.

I can see that the path specified in the @ApplicationPath is ignored: my resources can be accessed at /rest/production and not at /rest/system/production.

I've tried to change the URI to /rest/system instead of /rest, but to no avail:

```
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("").scheme("http").host("localhost").port(8084).path("/rest/system").build();
```

The application is deployed in the root context /rest, not /rest/system.

What am I missing?

Of course as a workaround I could change the resource path from "/production" to "/system/production", but I would like to know why the application path is ignored.

Comment: The annotation gets extracted in a ServletContainerInitializer (mainly in war deployments). I don't know if grizzly supports this. Maybe you need to try to configure the app as a war, and deploy the war. I've never tried to use a war with grizzly, so I'm not sure how to configure it. But I know the initializer doesn't get called with programmatic configuration like this.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet. I've found an example about how to programmatically configure grizzly with a web app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593983/using-jersey-with-grizzly?rq=1 . I'll give it a chance.

Comment: That's not it. This is already what the `GrizzlyWebContainerFactory` is doing under the hood. What I mean is to package your project as a WAR, then configure grizzly to deploy that war. The ApplicationPath was really made for WAR deployments for automatic discovery, not for embedded deployments. There's no real need for it. since you can configure the URL programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the code that creates and initializes the server to:

```
public void start() {
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("").scheme("http").host("localhost").port(8084).build();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(16);
    String applicationPackageName = RestApplication.class.getPackage().getName();
    String productionPackageName = ProductionService.class.getPackage().getName();
    params.put(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, productionPackageName + "," + applicationPackageName);

    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri);
    WebappContext context = new WebappContext("system", "/rest/system");
    ServletRegistration registration = context.addServlet("jersey", ServletContainer.class);
    registration.setInitParameters(params);
    registration.addMapping("/*");
    context.deploy(server);

    server.start();
}
```

A Web Application context is created and serves the resources at the desired path. Since the servlet container initializer is not invoked in this programmatic approach, the ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS property is not set.

I thought that setting this property were doing the job, but it does not. Thanks to @peeskillet for the hint.